# ckeck the category of post before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model call Post, and other model call Category, where 1 post have multiple category.

In my form of new post  I have all my category like a button, I select the category doing click and change the class of my button. (show press button)

When I click in the submit button, How to know if the user click in any category? It is possible do this without javascript/ajax.

I want to do this check before save the Post

this is my button of category

```
  .row-fluid
    .field
      = f.label :category
      - @categories.each do |cate|
        = button_tag(:class=> 'categoryButton', :type =>'button', :value=> cate.id) do
          = content_tag(:strong, cate.name)

  .row-fluid
    .actions.pull-right
      = f.submit t(:save)


:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.categoryButton').click(function(){
    if (this.className == "categoryButtonCambiado")
      this.className=this.className ="categoryButton"
    else
      this.className=this.className ="categoryButtonCambiado"
  });
  })
```

any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably implement this as checkbox rather than button, it would be more natural, both for the implementation and for what user is used to.

If you really want to use a button, you can still add checkboxes, make them hidden (using the `hidden` class, since you seem to be using bootstrap), and check/uncheck them using javascript :

```
  .row-fluid
    .field
      = f.label :category
      - @categories.each do |cate|
        = check_box_tag "categories[#{cate.id}]", '1', false, class: 'hidden'
        = button_tag(:class=> 'categoryButton', :type =>'button', :value=> cate.id) do
          = content_tag(:strong, cate.name)

  .row-fluid
    .actions.pull-right
      = f.submit t(:save)


:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.categoryButton').click(function(){
    if (this.className == "categoryButtonCambiado")
      this.className=this.className ="categoryButton"
      $(this).prop( 'checked', true );
    else
      this.className=this.className ="categoryButtonCambiado"
      $(this).prop( 'checked', false );
  });
  })
```

You can then retrieve checked category ids in controller :

```
params[:categories]
```

Btw, this is off-topic, but you should really consider putting your javascript in dedicated files, it's really easy with rails asset pipeline.